# PHP short if statement with continue key word and ommit the else part

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I have a for loop like

```
for ($x=1; $x<=5; $x++){
    ($x == 3)? continue : true;
    //some code here
}
```

now on execution I am getting error

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'continue' (T_CONTINUE) in
>   /var/www/html/all.php on line 21

Now, this leave me with 2 questions:

1. Can I use continue key word inside short if statement?
2. For the else part of the short if, can binary values like true or false be used, and if not then how can I use short if statement if I have nothing to do for the else part.

Comment: Using a ternary operator here is actually *longer* than `if ($x == 3) continue;`, since you need to fill in the second `:` part with some useless value…

Comment: doesn't seem to be a way to do this. `$x == 3 or continue;` also returns an error. as well as `break` and `goto`. `exit` works though.

Answer (score 8):

`continue` is a *statement* (like `for`, or `if`) and must appear standalone. It cannot be used as part of an *expression*. Partly because `continue` doesn't *return a value*, but in an expression every sub-expression must result in some value so the overall expression results in a value. That's the difference between a statement and an expression.

`cond ? a : b` means *use value `a` if `cond` is true else use value `b`*. If `a` is `continue`, there's no value there.

`true` does result in a value (`true`), so yes, it can be used as part of an expression.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `continue` inside short if-statement. Short if-statements is for returning values, like this

```
$val = $bool ? $one : $two;
```

Now, `$val` will have either the value of `$one` or the value of `$two`, depending of the truth value of `$bool`.

`continue` is no value, so it cannot be used in short if-statement. Use normal if-statement for this operation.

In this case, I would have done it like this:

```
for ($x=1; $x<=5; $x++){
    if($x == 3) continue;
    //some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use continue key word inside if statement like this; (according to PHP documentation)

```
<?php
 for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
  if ($i == 2)
      continue
  print "$i\n";
  }
?>
```